# codeigniter two different file_upload need two different configs

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Yup. The title says it all.  I have two file upload functions in a view and they need two different configs to upload files.

```
echo form_label('Product Image') . form_upload('prod_image','');
echo form_label('Product Manual') . form_upload('prod_manual','');
```

As the names imply, the first upload form should contain only an image file and upload it to an image folder.  The other should contain only a doc/pdf file and upload it to a manual folder.

In a controller, how can I give them two different configs? I can't find any info regarding it

Thank you in advance!

Comment: one by one you can upload. Initialize the configurations before do_upload call

Comment: @Sundar Is that only way to do it? :s

Comment: yes. otherwise use ajax upload and send the category variable to upload method and do the modification based on that

Comment: @Sundar I see... post your answer and I will accept it :) Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//open single form is enough and target to this method update the form field name appropriate to the document and image

```
//controlleer method
function do_upload()
{
 //upload image
  if($this->upload_image('field_name'))
  {
    //upload dsuccess
  }else{
     //error
  }

  //upload image
  if($this->upload_document('field_name'))
  {
    //upload dsuccess
  }else{
     //error
  }

}

//controlleer method
function upload_image($form_field_name)
{

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($form_field_name))
    {
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
       return true;
    }
}

//controlleer method
function upload_document($form_field_name)
{

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|pdf';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($form_field_name))
    {
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the form field name  $form_field_name = ''

Comment: Is it okay to call two form_open_multipart() functions in a view?

Comment: Just one more thing to add for other ppl with the same issue - Add '  $this->upload->initialize($config);'  in the code. Otherwise it complains that the path is not valid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32662/discussion-between-sundar-and-raccoon)